# What is wrong in my usage of cookies with LWP::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, authentication, cookies, lwp-useragent

With a real Firefox browser, my authentication through 'https://www.briefing.com/Login/subscriber.aspx' places a cookie on my hard drive.  Afterwards, when I start another session, I can bypass the authentication step and directly reach data page like 'https://www.briefing.com/investor/calendars/earnings/2018/08/09'.

In the code below, I am trying to duplicate the above, but to no avail.  What am I doing wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTTP::Cookies;
use LWP::UserAgent;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

# Let ua use cookies and gives it an empty jar
$ua->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());

# login to create cookies
# The field names are guessed, based on these web elements: 
# <input name="_textBoxUserName" id="_textBoxUserName" type="text">  
# <input name="_textBoxPassword" id="_textBoxPassword" type="password">   
my $url = 'https://www.briefing.com/Login/subscriber.aspx';
my $res = $ua->post($url,
                    '_textBoxUserName' => '*******',
                    '_textBoxPassword' => '*******');

# confirm that new cookies are indeed placed in the cookie jar
print join("\n", $ua->cookie_jar()->as_string);

# But URL still gets re-directed even though the cookie jar has been filled
$url = 'https://www.briefing.com/investor/calendars/earnings/2018/08/09';
$res = $ua->get($url);
print $res->content;
```

Comment: What is the path of the cookie? Is it for `/`? Did you compare the cookie you get that way from the one Firefox gets?

Comment: The print statement in my code shows that three "cookies" are inserted.  All three have path="/". With a real browswer (Chrome -- I cannot see actual content of the cookies under Firefox),  12 cookies are created under www.briefing.com and 4 under briefing.com.   Three of the 12 matched those created under $us->post() in the "name" but with slightly different "content" values.

Comment: With Firefox you can use the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) in the developer tools to inspect cookies.

Comment: Thx Mel.  Just saw that too on Google.  Actually, under preference, I can select "remove individual cookies" and there I could actually see inside directly without resorting to Storage Inspector.

Comment: It is expected that the content differs, but what is strange/maybe source of the problem is the fact that you do not get the same amount of them. Your code seems ok for me, it is maybe just that the browser, with various included images/css/fonts/scripts gets more cookies than with just a single query as you do.

Comment: Also note that some websites require that you first GET the page with the authentication form and **then** only submit it with credentials. Sometimes if you just do the POST without the first GET, the query is at best rejected or at least ignored as if you did not submit anything. Try to do a GET on the URL, and then post. Also try to use WWW::Mechanize instead of LWP::UserAgent as there may be hidden fields in the form you need to send too or other shenanigans that WWW::Mechanize is more suitable to handle than LWP::UserAgent which is too low in the stack.

Comment: I also tried with a user agent string:  $ua->agent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0'); to mimic a real browser.  It didn't make any difference.  Only 3 cookies inserted.   I also tried Firefox, which inserted 15 cookies (all under briefing.com).

Comment: Thanks Pat.  I was trying to get it to work with LWP.  I can always resort to Selenium but felt it was an over-kill.  Let me try the  get idea first.

Comment: So I added a line "$ua->get($url);" before "$ua->post($url, ....);" It does not make any difference.   Regarding WWW::Mechanize, I am not familiar with it.  Is there any benefit to use it instead of Selenium (with which I have some experience)?

Comment: What is `$res->status_line` and `$res->headers->as_string`?

Comment: There are 2 $res in my code (post and get).  For both of them, $res->status_line = '200 OK', but $res->headers->as_string is too long to fit here.   Is there way to attach files in Stack Overflow?  Or is there a way to message you directly?

Comment: `WWW::Mechanize` is "just" a wrapper on top of `LWP::UserAgent` but mimicks more closely what a real browser does (except the Javascript stuff). It is more suited for web scraping than only a pure HTTP client.

Comment: Thanks Patrick.  I will check out Mechanize someday.  For now, I already implemented a Selenium based solution.